# Async DbContext.SaveChanges EF 5, savechanges after returning a response (MVC/WebAPI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'd like to return the response to the client before paying the cost of saving changes to the DbContext.  Can I save changes after returning a response?  Simply throwing it into a ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem fails since the context is disposed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case your logic for when you dispose of the DbContext is too complex to use a `using` block; you'll need to manually dispose instead.  Your code might look more like:

```
DbContext context = null;
try
{
    context = new DbContext();
    var query = context.GetStuff();

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    });
}
catch
{
    //dispose of the context only if there was an exception, as it 
    //meant we weren't able to get into the async task and dispose of it there
    if (context != null)
        context.Dispose();

    throw;
}
```

Comment: I'm using a DbContext constructed with the controller, but your point is exactly right.  The workaround for me was to hang the dispose method until commit had finished.  Makes me wonder if adding a QueueCommit field to the context, and then on Dispose { if (QueueCommit) SaveChanges(); } is a good idea (with try/finally of course)